# How do we modify docker0 mtu in my k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to modify docker0 mtu to 1400 by`ifconfig docker0 mtu 1400` and it is successed.

but after a while, the mtu goes back to 1500. please help, how to modify docker0 in my k8s cluster.

Comment: what network plugin are you using? For calico you can do this https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/usage/configuration/mtu

Comment: thank you.  i find the solution and it is https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/13984#issuecomment-434995031

Comment: yes . I using canal(the same as calico) and you answer is solution too . thank you @TummalaDhanvi

Comment: cool adding the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MTU in Kubernetes can be configured from the CNI plugin.

Here is the documentation for Calico https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/networking/configuring/mtu